# How to sort by value "grand total" in pivot table using Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I use the below code to create a pivot table automatically by referencing a sheet id. I want to know how can I sort the pivot table using the Grand Total column. I can do it manually when I go to the spreadsheet but I want to do it automatically. I checked google sheets documentation [HERE](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html) But was not able to figure it out. Maybe it has something do withe creating a bucket but not sure.

This is my current working code without the sorting for the value part:

```
      {
        "requests": [
          {
            "updateCells": {
              "rows": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "pivotTable": {
                      "source": {
                        "sheetId": source_sheet_id,
                        "startRowIndex": 0,
                        "startColumnIndex": 0,
                        "endRowIndex": max_row_count,
                        "endColumnIndex": 3 #total columns
                      },
                      "rows": [
                        {
                          "sourceColumnOffset": code_index,
                          "showTotals": True,
                          "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                          "valueBucket": {
                            "buckets": [
                              {
                                "stringValue": "West"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "columns": [
                        {
                          "sourceColumnOffset": month_index,
                          "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                          "showTotals": True,
                          "valueBucket": {
                             "buckets": [
                              {
                                "stringValue": "Panel"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                        }
                      ],
                      "values": [
                        {
                          "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
                          "sourceColumnOffset": counts_index
                        }
                      ],
                      "valueLayout": "HORIZONTAL"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "start": {
                "sheetId": destination_sheet_id,
                "rowIndex": 0,
                "columnIndex": 0
              },
              "fields": "pivotTable"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: See the bottom-most example on this page: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data

Comment: I tried it but the pivot table just resort itself by the first column as a default. I could see it happening when I run the update ```{
    "requests": [
      {
        "sortRange": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": sheet_id,
            "startRowIndex": 2,
            "endRowIndex": max_row_count,
            "startColumnIndex": 0,
            "endColumnIndex": 20
          },
          "sortSpecs": [
            {
              "dimensionIndex": 17,
              "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }```

Comment: @Jonas Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked @mongotop. I posted the comment as an answer with some more explanation, would be great if you could accept and close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it after a long research.

The trick is adding an empty "valueBucket" key in each row, like this:

```
    "rows": [
  {
    "sourceColumnOffset": 0,
    "showTotals": true,
    "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
    "valueBucket": {}
  },
```

Then the rows will be ordered by the Grand Total column.

I found the answer here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SortOrder

It says: "For example, in a pivot table with one row group & two column groups, the row group can list up to two values. The first value corresponds to a value within the first column group, and the second value corresponds to a value in the second column group. **If no values are listed, this would indicate that the row should be sorted according to the "Grand Total" over the column groups**. If a single value is listed, this would correspond to using the "Total" of that bucket."

In your case, the data was taken from here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables

Check this Sheet example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5s03qLAVaLfUfkyvjZtllVNz0FxAmn2jEmL9wYVGh8/edit?usp=sharing

In the example, this function, based on your code, created the pivot table with the values ordered by Grand Total Column.

```
function makePivot() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheetId = sheet.getSheetByName("Data").getSheetId(); 

  // Create a new sheet which will contain our Pivot Table
  var pivotTableSheet = sheet.insertSheet("Pivot1");
  var pivotTableSheetId = pivotTableSheet.getSheetId();  

  var request = {    
    "updateCells": {
      "rows": {
        "values": [
          {
            "pivotTable": {
              "source": {
                "sheetId": sourceSheetId,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": 20,
                "endColumnIndex": 7
              },
              "rows": [
                {
                  "sourceColumnOffset": 0,
                  "showTotals": true,
                  "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                  "valueBucket": {}
                },
                {
                  "sourceColumnOffset": 1,
                  "showTotals": true,
                  "sortOrder": "DESCENDING",
                  "valueBucket": {}
                }
              ],
              "columns": [
                {
                  "sourceColumnOffset": 4,
                  "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                  "showTotals": true}
              ],
              "values": [
                {
                  "summarizeFunction": "SUM",
                  "sourceColumnOffset": 3
                }
              ],
              "valueLayout": "HORIZONTAL"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "start": {
        "sheetId": pivotTableSheetId,
        "rowIndex": 2,
        "columnIndex": 0
      },
      "fields": "pivotTable"
    }
  }

  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, sheet.getId());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Send a POST request to the following url (fill in your spreadsheetID): https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId:batchUpdate

Containing the following payload (insert actual value for grand total column number):

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "sortRange": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 10,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "endColumnIndex": 6
        },
        "sortSpecs": [
          {
            "dimensionIndex": Index of GrandTotal Column,
            "sortOrder": "ASCENDING"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See here for the full documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data (bottom-most example)

Comment: Thank you @anas ! That works for 1 millisecond and then the pivot table re-sort itself to the original view.